# Google Drive Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm writing a new Question on Google Drive API.

I'm trying to Upload a Base64 PDF File to a Folder on my Google Drive. I've successfully set up my APP Key and all other API Option, i can read the Files List on Google Drive folder, i'm able to create a new Folder if it doesn't exists, but i cannot upload a PDF Files, and i don't know why!

#### First Try

According to V3 API Documentation i've tried to do this (i'm using AngularJS):

```
gapi.client.drive.files.create({
    resource: {
        'name': 'My first PDF.pdf',
        'mimeType': 'application/pdf',
        'parents': [$folderID]
    },
    media: {
        'mimeType': 'application/pdf',
        'body': $file
    },
    fields: 'id'
})
.then(function($res){
    console.log('The Res', $res);
});
```

In `$res` Object there is the ID of the new File, but the new File is created without a name (Untitled) and is Empty (0Kb). If i remove the `media` key from the Object, the File will be created with right name and mimeType, but obviously it's without any content.

#### Second Try

Surfing into Google Developers Docs i've found another Methods, using Multipart (i'm using this Code from a Google Drive Example on GitHub https://github.com/googledrive/web-quickeditor/blob/master/src/components/drive/multipart.js).
According to this i've tried to do this:

```
var $metadata = {
    'name': 'My first PDF.pdf',
    'mimeType': 'application/pdf',
    'parents': [$folderID]
};
var $multipart = new MultiPartBuilder()
    .append('application/json', JSON.stringify($metadata))
    .append($mimeType, $file)
    .finish();
var $request = gapi.client.request({
    path: '/upload/drive/v3/files',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        uploadType: 'multipart',
        fields: 'id'
    },
    headers: {'Content-Type' : $multipart.type},
    body: $multipart.body
});
$request().then(function($res){
    console.log($res);
});
```

Also in this case i was able to create the file, with right filename and in the right folder, but as always, the file si Empty! In one case the files seems to be full (72Kb of Data), but opening it will cause a Corrupt File Error.

Could someone help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you go over the [uploading files in Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) guide?